# Disabling a Parent Window while a pop-up is open in c++

Tags: visual-c++

How do I disable a Parent Window while a pop-up is open in C++ Microsoft Visual Studio WinApi. Basically, I want my pop-up to act like a modal dialog. I found this message loop on the internet that says it should do this trick but it doesn't. When I open my application the parent window IS already disabled and I can't do anything with it. Below I'm going to provide the message loop I've used in my program. What should I do in order to make the Parent Window disabled while the pop-up is open and after closing the pop-up how do I enable the parent window back?

```
    BOOL fDone;
    INT  nResult = 0;

    int RunModalWindow(
        HWND hwndPopup,
        HWND hWndParent);

    if (hWndParent != NULL) {
        EnableWindow(hWndParent, FALSE);
    }

    MSG msg;

for (fDone = FALSE; !fDone; WaitMessage())

{

while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))

{

     if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)

     {

     fDone = TRUE;

     PostMessage(NULL, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

     break;

     }

            if (!IsDialogMessage(hwndPopup, &msg))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }

    if (hWndParent != NULL)
        EnableWindow(hWndParent, TRUE);

    DestroyWindow(hwndPopup);

    return nResult;
}
```